# searching on array items on a DynamoDB table

Tags: indexing, amazon-dynamodb, denormalization

I need to understand how one can search attributes of a DynamoDB that is part of an array.

So, in denormalising a table, say a person that has many email addresses. I would create an array into the person table to store email addresses.

Now, as the email address is not part of the sort key, and if I need to perform a search on an email address to find the person record. I need to index the email attribute.

1. Can I create an index on the email address, which is 1-many relationship with a person record and it's stored as an array as I understand it in DynamoDB.
2. Would this secondary index be global or local? Assuming I have billions of person records?

   3. If I could create it as either LSI or GSI, please explain the pros/cons of each.

thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stu's answer has some great information in it and he is right, you can't use an Array it's self as a key.

> What you CAN `sometimes` do is concatenate several variables (or an Array) into a single string with a known seperator (maybe '_' for example), and then use that string as a Sort Key.

I used this concept to create a composite Sort Key that consisted of multiple ISO 8061 date objects (DyanmoDB stores dates as ISO 8061 in String type attributes).  I also used several attributes that were not dates but were integers with a fixed character length.

By using the BETWEEN comparison I am able to individually query each of the variables that are concatenated into the Sort Key, or construct a complex query that matches against all of them as a group.

**In other words a data object could use a Sort Key like this:**
email@gmail.com_email@msn.com_email@someotherplace.com

Then you could query that (assuming you knew what the partition key is) with something like this:

`SELECT * FROM Users
WHERE User='Bob' AND Emails LIKE '%email@msn.com%'`

### YOU MUST know the partition key in order to perform a Query no matter what you choose as your Sort Key and no matter how that Sort Key is constructed.

I think the real question you are asking is what should my sort keys and partition keys be?  That will depend on exactly which queries you want to make and how frequently each type of query is used.

I have found that I have way more success with DynamoDB if I think about the queries I want to make first, and then go from there.

### A word on Secondary Indexes (GSI / LSI)

The issue here is that you still need to 'know' the Partition Key for your secondary data structure.  GSI / LSI help you avoid needing to create additional DynamoDB tables for the sole purpose of improving data access.

From Amazon:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html

To me it sounds more like the issue is selecting the Keys.

**LSI (Local Secondary Index)**
If (for your Query case) you don't know the Partition Key to begin with (as it seems you don't) then a Local Secondary Index won't help — since it has the SAME Partition Key as the base table.

**GSI (Global Secondary Index)**
A Global Secondary Index *could* help in that you can have a DIFFERENT Partition Key and Sort Key (presumably a partition key that you could 'know' for this query).

So you could use the Email attribute (perhaps composite) as the Sort Key on your GSI and then something like a service name, or sign-up stage, as your Partition Key.  This would let you 'know' what partition that user would be in based on their progress or the service they signed up from (for example).

*GSI / LSI still need to generate unique values using their keys so keep that in mind!*

Comment: Thank you Necevil. Unfortunately I do need to search directly on the child without knowledge of the partition key.

In other words, I do want to search the email address in order to retrieve the user record.

You see if I normalised it in normal SQL tables, I have two tables: Users and Emails. Emails table would have a foreign key to the Users table. Then I will be able to directly join the two tables and search on the email (and have the email attribute indexed).

Do I have to create two tables in DynamoDB? and join them like denormalised tables? But apparently you can't join tables.

Comment: @Bluetoba there are a few things here, first off its necessary to realize that a QUERY in DynamoDB is NOT required to do a lot of things, it just speeds up the process when compared to a SCAN of the whole table.  So you can for sure do the exact same thing you describe with SQL tables using a SCAN and no changes to your keys.  You can also create a Global Secondary Index with a DIFFERENT partition key (which you can 'know' for your Query) to narrow down the number of entries you are retrieving relative to a full SCAN.  Updated answer with a few bits on secondary indexes.

Comment: Thank you @Necevil. I am have begun to understand the purpose of GSIs over LSIs. However, I was under the impression that I could not create secondary indexes based on an attribute of an array because it's not a SCALAR type. So, how can I create a GSI with the email addresses as part of the key as I thought you suggested it? Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Its worth getting the terminology right to start with. DynamoDB [supported data types](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes) are

**Scalar** - *String, number, binary, boolean*

**Document** - *List, Map*

**Sets** - *String Set, Number Set, Binary Set*

I think you are suggesting you have an attribute that contains a list of emails. The attribute might look like this

```
Emails: ["one@email.com", "two@email.com", "three@email.com"]
```

There are a couple of relevant points about Key attributes described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_KeySchemaElement.html). Firstly keys must be top-level attributes (they cant be nested in JSON documents). Secondly they must be of scalar types (i.e. String, Number or Binary).

As your list of emails is not a scalar type, you cannot use it in a key or index.

Given this schema you would have to perform a [scan](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html), in which you would set the [FilterExpression](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html#DDB-Scan-request-FilterExpression) on your Emails attribute using the [CONTAINS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Condition.html) operator.

Comment: Thanks Stu, once again for giving me the understanding. So, to recap: those emails ae not "string" data type, but they are more precisely called "String Set"? Because String Sets are not Scalar, I could not put an index on them.

Have I got it right? 

Then the next question I am making, which I will respond to Necevil' reply is regarding denormalising tables. If one of the benefits of the NOSQL databases is to place child records directly into the parent table, e.g. emails above. But I can't actually put an index directly on the child, then what would be the best practice in doing so?

Comment: By the way, how do I add a new line in the stacoverflow.com comment here? I put a carriage return, but my comment above don't come up nice.  Sorry!

Comment: Correct. A list of emails is a String Set. You cannot index a String Set.

Comment: Some options for you include doing a Scan on your Emails String Set (see answer). If you really want to index the emails you probably need a separate table of emails (i.e. Email, Username), where one user can have multiple items.

Comment: Thanks Stu, I think I got the idea that within the same partition the scanning process is still very quick because the data is adjacent to each other.